# Set value for all values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So basically I have an Array and I want to use the same IF-statement for all values without having to copy-paste the IF-statement so many times. E.g.

```
if(NewArray[] < 10){
NewArray[] = NewArray + 1;
}
```

Is this in any way possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use a for loop.

Comment: Thanks @KostasC but it must happen like all at the same time. So it cant be a loop.

Comment: The code is meaningless. It sure won't compile. Are you trying to assign values to all array elements? Are you trying to extend the array size? Or are you trying to increment the value of each element by one?

Comment: You will never be able to do it "all at the same time". Unless your code is multi-threaded, that doesn't even matter anyway.

Comment: At the same time is 'strange'. Computers have a limited number of cores. Usually things happen sequentially, but too fast to be visible. Use mutexes/critical sections to ensure multi-threaded cohetence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a for loop. This code will solve your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int newArray[] = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length ; i ++){
        newArray[i] = i;
    }

    /* DISPLAY YOUR ARRAY */

    for(int integer : newArray){
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: Easy way to print an array: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray))`

Comment: if there is no problem to fill you array with the same value in all positions, you can use Arrays.fill() method.